# How to register properly a custom IdentityServer ConfigurationDbContext in Asp.Net Core 2?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to create my own ConfigurationDbContext from IdentityServer.

```
public class IdSrvConfigurationDbContext : ConfigurationDbContext<ConfigurationDbContext>
{
    public IdSrvConfigurationDbContext(DbContextOptions<IdSrvConfigurationDbContext> options, ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions) : base(options.ChangeOptionsType<ConfigurationDbContext>(), storeOptions)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //mylogic here  
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Now in the Startup.cs I tried the following

```
    services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                // (DbContextOptionsBuilder) paramBuilder
                options.ConfigureDbContext = paramBuilder =>
                    paramBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly));
            });
```

Now when I am trying to run migrations over my project, it goes through all the startup logic injection and ending with this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up your `IdSrvConfigurationDbContext` type to expect a `DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext>` instead. That’s the type the underlying `ConfigurationDbContext` expects and that’s also what the IdentityServer is going to pass down.

Usually, you should always use a typed `DbContextOptions<T>` matching to the context. But when inheriting from existing contexts, this can be a bit difficult. But in those cases, you don’t need to worry much: The typed options are only used to differentiate between the various configured options. So as long as each context in your application still uses a separate type, there shouldn’t be any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for me to define custom ConfigurationDbContext/PersistedGrantDbContext was to set `HasMaxLength` over some properties. That's because in production we use NDBCLUSTER engine and if length is not defined or it's too big default type within MySQL will be `longtext`. This causes a problem, because NDBCLUSTER doesn't support `text` family data-types.

Within extension method I am plugging custom db context and at the same time setting the common ConfigurationDbContext/PersistedGrantDbContext. I guess IdentityServer uses them for the internal stuff.

```
    services 
        .AddIdentityServer(options => {})
        .AddConfigurationStore<ApplicationConfigurationDbContext>()
        .AddConfigurationStoreCache()
        .AddOperationalStore<ApplicationPersistedGrantDbContext>();

    services.AddDbContext<PersistedGrantDbContext>(options => ContextBuilder(options, connectionString));
    services.AddDbContext<ConfigurationDbContext>(options => ContextBuilder(options, connectionString));
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationPersistedGrantDbContext>(options => ContextBuilder(options, connectionString));
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationConfigurationDbContext>(options => ContextBuilder(options, connectionString));

    static public void ContextBuilder(DbContextOptionsBuilder options, string connectionString)
    {
        options.UseMySql(connectionString: connectionString,
                 ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString),
                 dbOptions => dbOptions.MigrationsAssembly(DataExtensions.MigrationAssemblyName));
    }
```

That way migrations are created and applied properly and I didn't face any problems during the runtime.